# How to do Python f strings in triple quotes

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a fairly simple requests script in a loop, which I need to pass the list item in as one of the parameters. I've done some reading and understand that f strings require double curly braces instead of single, but it's still not working.

```
import requests

org_names = ['name 1', 'name 2']

for name in org_names:
    values = f"""
      {
        "name": "{{name}}",
        "groupId": "xxxx"
      }
    """

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'xxxxx'
    }

    response = requests.post('https://xxxx', data=values, headers=headers)

    data = response.json()
```

This gives me the following error

```
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

I've also tried using format(), as follows:

```
for name in org_names:
    values = """
      {
        "name": "{{}}",
        "groupId": "xxxx"
      }
    """.format(name)
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
KeyError: '\n        "name"'
```

Comment: Did you swap `{{` for `{` and vice versa? `{{` is literal brace, while `{` opens a new format slot

Comment: Don't use double bracket. It should have single curly bracket `{ name}`

Comment: Don't generate JSON manually; use `json.dumps(dict(name=name, gropuId="xxxx"))`.

Comment: And `requests` will do this for you: `requests.post('...', json=dict(name=name, groupID="xxxx"))`.

Comment: I have tried using {name} originally, but a search of the internet showed people recommending changing it for {{}}, which didn' fix it.

Comment: It wasn't `{name}` causing the problem, but the `{...}`  defining the object.

Comment: Where did you read that f-strings require double-braces to open a format slot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `{{` in a format string to represent a literal `{`, so your string should look like

```
values = f"""
  {{
    "name": "{name}",
    "groupId": "xxxx"
  }}
"""
```

However, there is no need to generate JSON yourself. `requests` will do that for you if you use the `json` keyword argument:

```
 response = requests.post('https://xxxx',
                          json={'name': name, 'groupId': 'xxxx'},
                          headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
org_names = ['name 1', 'name 2']

for name in org_names:
    values = f'''
      {{
        name: "{name}",
        groupId: "xxxx",
      }}
   '''
```

`values` will be formatted like the following in the for loop:

```py
      {
        name: "name 1",
        groupId: "xxxx",
      }
```

Is that what you are looking for?